# Expose master to cluster-external addresses when using redis sentinel in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, redis-sentinel

I am trying to deploy a Redis sentinel topology into my Kubernetes cluster. I am using the [bitnami-redis](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis) helm chart which, for non-sentinel deployments, has worked great so far.

I am essentially using the example helm values found [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/redis/values.yaml), with the exception of replacing most `type: ClusterIP` with `type: LoadBalancer` in order to get access to these services from outside the cluster.

I have deployed the helm chart with `cluster.enabled=true` and `sentinel.enabled=true` and am currently able to access the sentinel node from outside my cluster (using `redis-cli -h {external_sentinel_ip} -p 26379`. However, when I try to ask the sentinel for the addresses to the current master, it is returning me a cluster-local IP address.

Example output from `redis-cli`...

```
{external_sentinel_ip}:26379> sentinel get-master-addr-by-name mymaster
1) "{cluster_local_ip}"  #    <-- Here
2) "6379"
```

My external clients who are connecting to this sentinel instance are outside the cluster, so they cannot reach the master using this IP.

In the [bitnami docs](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis#master-slave-with-sentinel) they explicitly mention `This command will return the address of the current master, which can be accessed from inside the cluster.`.

I'm wondering if it is possible to configure this helm chart in such a way that redis will return external IPs for these master instances.

Any ideas? The docs do not present such a use case, but I can't believe this has never been a requirement before.

Comment: Bitnami developer here. In other charts like Kafka we implemented exposing all the IP addresses of the nodes so that would not be a problem. For  example in our redis-cluster chart (another topology without sentinel) we have that support. Could you open a ticket in our bitnami/charts repo for requesting that feature?

Comment: Hey @JavierSalmeron ! I actually already did, https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/3524 -- Apparently (and understandably) it is a larger change, so may not get priority on your side. Thanks for taking a look!